# Get the n-th closest descendant using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the many similar documents shown below. The names of `random0`, `random1`, and `random2` tags vary across documents. The number of list tags is not fixed. How do I use `xpath` to get the n-th closest descendant list tag from the content tag i.e. if `n == 1` return `1,2,3,10,11, 12`; if `n == 2` return `4,5,6`; and so on. Note: The closest descendant list tag may be a child, grandchild or even further.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
     <random0>
        <list>1</list>
        <list>2</list>
        <list>3</list>
        <random1>
            <list>4</list>
            <list>5</list>
            <list>6</list>
            <random2>
                <list>7</list>
                <list>8</list>
                <list>9</list>
            </random2>
        </random1>
        <list>10</list>
        <list>11</list>
        <list>12</list>
    </random0>
</content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So breaking this down, you need to

- Find all the descendant elements, whatever their names, that have any `list` children
- Pick the *n*th one of those
- extract all its `list` children

```
descendant::*[list][$number]/list
```

or possibly

```
descendant-or-self::*[list][$number]/list
```

if you want to allow for the first lot of lists being directly inside the context node (e.g. if you're starting from the `random0` rather than the `content`).

**XSLT example**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
      <xsl:copy-of select="descendant-or-self::*[list][2]/list" />
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result>
  <list>4</list>
  <list>5</list>
  <list>6</list>
</result>
```

---

NB. This is one of those corner cases in XPath that exposes the subtle differences between `descendant::` and `.//`.  The obvious shorthand of `.//*[list][$num]/list` will *not* do the same as `descendant::*[list][$num]/list`, it will instead pick out all the elements-with-list-children that are the *n*th element-with-list-children within their respective parents, which in your example means *all* of them if n=1 and nothing at all otherwise.  You'd have to add parentheses to make it behave the same as the `descendant::` version - `(.//*[list])[$num]/list`